# Listen for changes of input validity state reliable

Tags: dom-events, constraint-validation-api

Can I listen to changes of [`ValidityState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState?retiredLocale=de) of an input element reliable? It seems that not in all cases an event is fired.

- `invalid` event is only fired when element enters the invalid state. It is not fired when the reason for invalid state changes (e.g. from `valueMissing` to `badInput`).
- `input` event is only fired when user enters a valid input. If user enters an invalid input (e.g. partially filled time input) the event is not fired.

I run into this issue with `<input type="time">`. I noticed two scenarios, in which the application is not notified about a change of the validity state:

1. `<input type="time" required>` is invalid due to `valueMissing` and changes to be invalid due to `badInput` when user partially fills it.
2. `<input type="time">` is invalid due to `badInput` and user clear the input causing the input to get valid again *without* a change of the value.

I'm trying to render the validation message with custom styling. But as I'm not able to listen to all potential changes of `InputElemen.validity` and `InputElement.validationMessage` the rendered validation message and the validity state of the element may get out of sync.

You can reproduce it playing with this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h4efs9y6/ You will notice that the validation message rendered by JavaScript and the validation message shown by the browser gets out of sync in some cases.

Comment: It seems to work if listening for `keyup` additionally: https://jsfiddle.net/jm4v5utb/ That even seems to be fired whenever the user enters a value. At least in the scenarios I tested. Need to check it more in detail and with other browsers than Firefox and Chrome only.